# Changing TFS 2012 Overview Home Screen Items

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is there any way to edit the TFS overview items?

[image]

For example, I want to get rid of the "Product Backlog Item" button on the screenshot above, as we have changed the naming convention of this to now be "Story".

Is this possible? If so, where do I navigate to which will enable me to edit this screen?

Answer (score 1):

I think your BAU Scrum Project is using Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum Process Template. you need to change it to MSF for agile Developement Process Template so that it will be called as userstory.

More details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752.aspx